# Use Arduino Yun Shield as ISP for bootloaded ATMega328-PU

Tags: shields, arduino-yun, atmega328, isp, icsp

My question is how do I replace the Aarduino Uuno board in this circuit:
[image]

...With an Arduino Yun shield? I can setup the hardware - ICSP configuration is easy enough - but how do I go about using the IDE to do this? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly unlikely you will be able to do it from the IDE. Instead you will have to do it from the Yun's command line (SSH) using `avrdude` and the `linuxgpio` driver, or the handy `run-avrdude` script.

```
$ sudo run-avrdude bootloader.hex
```

where `bootloader.hex` is the bootloader file found somewhere in the IDE that you need to copy over to the Yun with `scp`.

You may find you need to tweak the fuse settings in the script to get the bootloader to work. I am not familiar with AVR fuses, but IIRC there is one that tells it to run the bootloader instead of the sketch. Just copy the values out of the boards.txt in the IDE and place them into a copy of `/usr/bin/run-avrdude` in your home directory.

Comment: The ATMega came with a bootloader intalled, so is the procedure the same for any other sketch? I've tried migrating the hex file onto a usb host and launching run-avrdude command - I was thrown an error message... Is that the correct-ish procedure though?